# Spliting Array divide by 16 using np python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So, I have array from image and I want to split it by 16. Not into 16 arrays, but each array will contain 16 bytes. I already try this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("images.tif")
img_array = np.array(img)

for i in img_array:
    newarr = np.array_split(i, 16)

print(newarr)
```

But I realized that it split into 16 arrays.

Comment: 16 bytes? Or 16 RGB pixels? Or maybe 16 RGBA pixels?

Comment: can you please provide more information regarding the desired outcome? please provde an example. Thanks